# perform action on bootstrap dropdown item selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie with bootstrap css. I found how to use it from it's documentations on site.

Here is demo:

[CODEPAN DEMO](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/qklCy)

Problem is:

I want to display `Category` on dropdown editbox. When user click on arrow, 4 category should be displayed.

[image]

Below dropdown menu there is one `div` with image and description, which gets data from db. For each category selection(from dropdow menu), content of this `div` will change. currently menu items also does not appear when clicked.

**Changing the content of `div` based on dropdown menu item selection has been asspain for me.**

how to do this?

Comment: The dropdown box doesn't have any data in it? 

Should the dropdown have 4 options, and when you click one, the grey div below should have its content updated?

Answer (score 0):

Load dropdown js

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: dropdown.js v3.0.2
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) { "use strict";

  // DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var backdrop = '.dropdown-backdrop'
  var toggle   = '[data-toggle=dropdown]'
  var Dropdown = function (element) {
    var $el = $(element).on('click.bs.dropdown', this.toggle)
  }

  Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent  = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    clearMenus()

    if (!isActive) {
      if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && !$parent.closest('.navbar-nav').length) {
        // if mobile we we use a backdrop because click events don't delegate
        $('<div class="dropdown-backdrop"/>').insertAfter($(this)).on('click', clearMenus)
      }

      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('show.bs.dropdown'))

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      $parent
        .toggleClass('open')
        .trigger('shown.bs.dropdown')

      $this.focus()
    }

    return false
  }

  Dropdown.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    if (!/(38|40|27)/.test(e.keyCode)) return

    var $this = $(this)

    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent  = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    if (!isActive || (isActive && e.keyCode == 27)) {
      if (e.which == 27) $parent.find(toggle).focus()
      return $this.click()
    }

    var $items = $('[role=menu] li:not(.divider):visible a', $parent)

    if (!$items.length) return

    var index = $items.index($items.filter(':focus'))

    if (e.keyCode == 38 && index > 0)                 index--                        // up
    if (e.keyCode == 40 && index < $items.length - 1) index++                        // down
    if (!~index)                                      index=0

    $items.eq(index).focus()
  }

  function clearMenus() {
    $(backdrop).remove()
    $(toggle).each(function (e) {
      var $parent = getParent($(this))
      if (!$parent.hasClass('open')) return
      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown'))
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
      $parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown')
    })
  }

  function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') //strip for ie7
    }

    var $parent = selector && $(selector)

    return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
  }


  // DROPDOWN PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  var old = $.fn.dropdown

  $.fn.dropdown = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('dropdown')

      if (!data) $this.data('dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }

  $.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown


  // DROPDOWN NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.dropdown.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.dropdown = old
    return this
  }


  // APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
  // ===================================

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)

}(jQuery);
```